# AJAX Request in .net MVC works in Chrome, not Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have recently come into a problem that I have had quite a bit of trouble solving. I am attempting to make a call to a controller with an AJAX request using JQuery. The request (which I will post below) works just fine in Google Chrome, but not Firefox in IE.

In Firefox, the request will immediately fail.

In Internet Explorer, the request will complete, but then the form will POST back to the controller after the AJAX request finishes.

Here is the code for my AJAX request and it's associated form:

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[id="usersLoggedForm"]').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(e) {

        var serviceURL = '/SystemChecker/GetUsersLogged?buster=' + new Date().getTime();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                LoginInterval: $('#LoginInterval').val(),
                LoginPeriodicity: $('#LoginPeriodicity').val()
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });


        function successFunc(data, status) {
            $("#usersLogged").text(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }

    });
});
```

Html

```
<form id="usersLoggedForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>SystemResponse</legend>
        <select id="LoginInterval" name="LoginInterval">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
        </select>
        <select id="LoginPeriodicity" name="LoginPeriodicity">
            <option value="n">Minutes</option>
            <option value="hh">Hours</option>
            <option value="yy">Years</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input id="usersLoggedSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a total JQuery and AJAX noob.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return false` to prevent the default submit action.

```
$('form[id="usersLoggedForm"]').submit(function (e) {
    // ... snip ...

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This seems to have had no effect, I have also tried the `e.preventDefault()` method, and that seems to halt my code entirely, regardless of browser choice.

Comment: Okay, haha, I was putting in the wrong place! Thank you Knelis! Is there any reason why this occurs, or why I have to return false? Is the false just a flag to tell IE to not continue with another request?

Comment: You shouldn't have to rebind `submit`. Could you try it without?

Comment: You're subscribing to the `submit` event. Your code will be reached first, but by default, the browser is also listening for that event to submit the form. If you don't want the browser to do anything after you've done something, always return `false`. Same is true e.g. for a `click` event on an `<a>` element. If you don't return `false`, the browser assumes `true` and will also execute its own event handler. In this case, because you `unbind` first, I guess Firefox and Chrome no longer subscribe to the event even when you `bind()` it again.

Comment: I reverted back to using `$('form[id="usersLoggedForm"]').submit(function (e)` and it still works.

Comment: Thank you Knellis, this is the first spot where I have seen it explained in a way that it makes sense to me.